# Is it possible to drag ReorderableListView items to another ReorderableListView?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to drag an item from one ReorderableListView into another ReorderableListView.

It seems it is only possible by using a regular ListView with Dragable and DragTarget widgets and without the look and feel of a ReorderableListView.

Am I right or is there a way?

Comment: did you solve it? If this is not possible I would also be interested if it is possible to drag multiple subsequent items at once within a single list?

Comment: I am also wondering how to do this. Did anyone ever find a solution? It seems that a `Draggable` widget inside a `ReorderableListView` loses its draggable functionality.

Comment: Im also interested to know the answer to this

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit delayed but I'm leaving this answer for anyone else that landed here after searching:

Consider using this flutter package:
https://pub.dev/packages/drag_and_drop_lists

[image: gif of items and lists being reordered]

> ### Features
>
> - Reorder elements between multiple lists
> - Reorder lists
> - Drag and drop new elements from outside of the lists
> - Vertical or horizontal layout
> - Use with drag handles, long presses, or short presses
> - Expandable lists
> - Can be used in slivers
> - Prevent individual lists/elements from being able to be dragged
> - Easy to extend with custom layouts

Comment: This library doesn't support using builders, so performance is pretty poor if there are a lot of items in the list, because all items are rendered at once...